# How do I list IRC server's channels using Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, irc

I would like to list the server's channels when I log into an IRC sevrer. How can I do that?

I tried to override the *signedOn* method:

```
def signedOn(self):
    print "connected to the server..."
    self.sendLine("/LIST")
```

but then I don't know if I get something back from this request and how to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Good point lets submit a patch on a ticket I just created to have this feature added.
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4929

Till then just `sendLine('LIST')` should work

Comment: How do I read the response from `sendLine('LIST')`? I tried to override `dataReceived(self, data)` method but I get everything ... and it seems that I don't get the channel list.

Comment: Override irc_RPL_LISTSTART, irc_RPL_LIST, and irc_RPL_LISTEND